# Divide integer by a list to create a new list

Tags: python, list, range

I've created a list of number in a specified range. I now want to divide an value by each element in the list, and then add that new value to a new list.
Heres what I've got:

```
Y = []
value = 55 #can be any value of my choosing
newx = list(range(50,500,10))
newy = value/(newx)**2
Y.append(newy)
```

I keep getting TypeError with unsupported operand types for ** or pow(): list and int and I don't know why. NOTE: The ** is a syntax for power i.e 1/(x^2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One "clean" option to do it is to use numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
value = 55 #can be any value of my choosing
Y = np.arange(50,500,10)
Y = value/(Y)**2
```

You got an error since in python you cannot take a square of a list (and you also cannot devide a number by a list). numpy array allows you to take a square and to do this division and many other mathematical operations.

Comment: yeah I've looked at using a numpy array, but I get this error now (using your above code): Value Error: x and y must have the same first dimension but have shapes (45,) and (1,45) ??

Comment: This sounds strange... I run my code on both python 2 and python 3 and it worked well. Could you tell me which particular line of code throws the error?

Comment: @Miriam: `Y.append(newy)` is useless, and probably the source of the error. You're creating a list with one single element : a `numpy.array`

Comment: line 1 according to the console

Comment: @Eric this line did not throw me an error (python allows to create a list and append to it a numpy list), but I removed it anyway, as it is not needed.

Comment: @ James Crampton you mean the import line? or the line with the Y=[]? Try to run the edited version. I changed the name newy to Y in case you use Y later in the code.

Comment: @Miriam: Sure, it doesn't throw an error in itself. But using `Y` might have been the problem afterwards.

Comment: @Eric o I see, that make sense. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: the code produces a nice 1/x^2 curve when tested on my Mac in python, however when I transfer this to ubuntu where I need it, it just produces a list of integer 0's for newy and not decimals. how can I convert  these?

Comment: Write Y = float(value)/(Y)**2 instead of Y = value/(Y)**2. Alternatively, you could set value=55.0 in the line where you define value.

Comment: @JamesCrampton: Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your description says what you *want* to do: divide a value by each element in a list. But that's not what you're actually doing, which is trying to divide the value by the list itself. You should do what you say you want to:

```
Y = [value/v for v in newx]
```

(I don't understand what the `**` is for, you don't mention that anywhere.)

Comment: The answer has been updated with a short explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) :

```
newy = [value/x**2 for x in newx]
```

The error you get is because the square of a list isn't defined.

The square of a [`numpy.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) is defined though, and would be a new array with the square of each element from the original array.

Depending on the value and range you're working with, you might want to convert the `int` to `float` first. You could get `0`s otherwise :

```
>>> value = 55
>>> newx = range(50, 500, 10)
>>> [value/x**2 for x in newx]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

But :

```
>>> [value/float(x)**2 for x in newx]
[0.022, 0.015277777777777777, 0.011224489795918367, 0.00859375, 0.006790123456790123, 0.0055, 0.004545454545454545, 0.0038194444444444443, 0.003254437869822485, 0.0028061224489795917, 0.0024444444444444444, 0.0021484375, 0.0019031141868512112, 0.0016975308641975309, 0.0015235457063711912, 0.001375, 0.0012471655328798186, 0.0011363636363636363, 0.0010396975425330812, 0.0009548611111111111, 0.00088, 0.0008136094674556213, 0.0007544581618655693, 0.0007015306122448979, 0.0006539833531510107, 0.0006111111111111111, 0.0005723204994797086, 0.000537109375, 0.000505050505050505, 0.0004757785467128028, 0.0004489795918367347, 0.0004243827160493827, 0.00040175310445580715, 0.0003808864265927978, 0.0003616042077580539, 0.00034375, 0.0003271861986912552, 0.00031179138321995464, 0.00029745808545159546, 0.0002840909090909091, 0.00027160493827160494, 0.0002599243856332703, 0.00024898143956541424, 0.00023871527777777777, 0.00022907122032486465]
```